# grunt-php: 'php' is not a recognized as an internal or extrernal command

Tags: php, server, gruntjs

I try to run `grunt-php`, but I always get the warning:

> Warning: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "php
>   --version" 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have installed xamp and added the path to my environment variables, where my php.exe is located:

```
name: path
value: C:\xampp\php\
```

But I still get the warning. In my `gruntfile.js`, I only copied these lines from the document:

```
php: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            keepalive: true,
            open: true,
            port: 5000
        }
    }
},
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: Where is the XAMPP path added? If you type `echo %PATH%` in cmd.exe prompt do you still see it?

Comment: ok after restarting it worked... didn't know that